# Jersey: call another API implementation in the background

Tags: java, proxy, jersey, jax-rs

I have a `jax-rs` API with three implementations (let's call them `mock`, `legacy` and `new`). Now what I'd like is to create some sort of a proxy feature, which would work followingly:

- let's consider some two of these `master` and `slave` implementations.
- a call to `master` implementation would be intercepted by this proxy, which would asynchronously call the `slave` implementation.
- no matter what the result of `slave` would be, response to the original call would always come from `master` implementation.
- the response would never be delayed (or affected at all) by the `slave`'s result (hence the asynchronous point).

My idea was to somehow hijack jersey's dispatching process (ideally at the point where the [Invocable](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/model/Invocable.java) object and request arguments are already available and then use [jersey's extension Proxy client](http://blog.alutam.com/2012/05/04/proxy-client-on-top-of-jax-rs-2-0-client-api/) to call the other API. The problem is that I don't know jersey's internals all that well so I don't know how to create such feature. But still, this should be possible, as for example jersey's [ConfiguredValidator](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/inject/ConfiguredValidator.java) has exactly the arguments I'd need in method `validateResourceAndInputParams`.

To summarize in somewhat-pseudo-code, the feature (working as a request filter of some sort) would do just about this:

```
void doFeature(Invocable invocable, Object[] args) {
     new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            jerseyClientProxyWrapper.call(invocable, args);
        } finally { /* loging etc */  }
    }).start();
}
```

Any idea how to create and register such feature?

Comment: I'm curious about your use case for this kind of thing...

Comment: @MartínStraus we have and old api that we're migrating to a new one. It esentially follows these steps: 1. create a "new api" wrapper implementation of the old (`legacy` API), 2. migrate client services to the new `legacy` implementation, 3. add this proxy to it so the actual `new` implementation starts filling up with data and then 4. test and move to production.

Answer (score 2):

1) Jersey server provides support to both `Filter` and `Interceptor` if that is what you are looking for. You can spawn your async call to slave intercepting the request and let the call to master flow as usual. These filters can be used to insert logging/custom authentication and many of such needs.

There are [`ContainerResponseFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) (e.g you will need this to customize the response) and `[ContainerRequestFilter][2]`

An example to call the different URL is

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class RedirectFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext reqContext) throws IOException {

      // redirect conditionally
      if (shouldRedirect(reqContext)) {
          reqContext.setRequestUri(URI.create("/slave"));
      }
  }

  private boolean shouldRedirect(ContainerRequestContext reqContext) {
      //todo it should be conditional return
      return true;
  }
}
```

And then your resource:

```
@Path("/")
public class MasterSlaveResource {

  @GET
  @Path("/master")
  public String getResponse() {
      return "master response";
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/slave")
  public String getTempResponse() {
      return "slave response";
  }
}
```

Of Course this sends request to either slave or master, but I am sure you can tweak it.

2) If they do not suffice your requirement, you can access the `HttpServletRequest` itself in the Resource and can Dispatch/delegate/send it t

@Context final HttpServletRequest request,

Comment: Well, how would I go on about tweaking this to actually make two calls?

Comment: Now that i am thinking more, was just wondering, what prevents you from doing an elementary, new separate HTTP call to slave in filter, (or even in Resource) in separate thread, and return the usual response from master?
 (after the slave thread is started)